# Why does AtomicParsley retrieves me an error on some specific files

Tags: c++, tags

I work with **AtomicParsley** to automatically tag files.

All files can be tagged, but some gives me this error:

**AtomicParsley error: the insufficient space to retag the source file**

I don't understand the C++ code of Atomic Parsley, where the message is displayed:

```
if (dynUpd.updage_by_padding && rewrite_original) {
    fclose(temp_file);
    uint64_t metadata_len = findFileSize(temp_file_name);

    temp_file = APar_OpenFile(temp_file_name, "rb");
    fclose(source_file);
    source_file = APar_OpenFile(ISObasemediafile, "r+b");
    if (source_file == NULL) {
      fclose(temp_file);
      remove(temp_file_name);
      fprintf(stdout,
              "AtomicParsley error: the original file was no longer "
              "found.\nExiting.\n");
      exit(1);
    } else if (!(dynUpd.optimization_flags & MEDIADATA__PRECEDES__MOOV) &&
               metadata_len != (dynUpd.first_mdat_atom->AtomicStart -
                                dynUpd.initial_update_atom->AtomicStart)) {
      fclose(temp_file);
      remove(temp_file_name);
      fprintf(stdout,
              "AtomicParsley error: the insufficient space to retag the source "
              "file (%" PRIu64 "!=%" PRIu64 ").\nExiting.\n",
              metadata_len,
              dynUpd.first_mdat_atom->AtomicStart -
                  dynUpd.initial_update_atom->AtomicStart);
      exit(1);
    }
```

As if the metadata length had changed... Or should it be too big?

Any idea?